# Java Mouse Clicking Issue

Tags: java, window, mouse

Okay, so I created a pong game and it's cool and all but every time I go to the game I have to click on the window to use any controls. I was wondering if there is any way to be able to use the controls ( like w s a d ) without having to click on the window. Just a question. Thanks if you answer and sorry that I can't vote you up because I don't got enough reputation.

Comment: The short answer is, no.  Not unless you want to use JNI/JNA, but that would be kind of weird because every time you pressed "W" any where, you game would update...

Comment: That kind of stinks because every time I try to play my game I have to quickly click on the window to start controlling my guy or I will die very quick.

Comment: Ahhh, that sounds like a different issue, are you using `KeyListener` by chance...?

Comment: Yeah for my controls.

Answer (score 0):

`KeyListener` is well known for having focus related issues.  This basically boils down to the fact that `KeyListener` will only respond to key presses if the component it is attached to is focusable and has focus.

Instead, you should try using the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which allows you to control the focus granuality, to the extent that so long as the window has focus, you can respond to key events (so long as some other component doesn't consume them first ;))